# Regular expression to match particular starting word or nothing

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to come up with the correct regex for the following scenario.

Let's say you have to match a word either starts with http- or nothing

eg : http-test-data, test-data should be a match but xyz-test-data shouldn't be a match

the regex i came up so far is

(?:http-)?(test-data)

but it matches xyz-test-data as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the following:

```
(?:http-|^)(test-data)
```

This tests for either a positive look-behind of `http-` or for the beginning of the string before `test-data`.

For example, for the sample data as follows:

```
http-test-data
xyz-test-data
http-test-data
xyz-test-data
test-data
yes-yes-test-data
-test-data
```

It yeilds:

```
http-test-data
http-test-data
test-data
```

Comment: This is the one i was really expecting so i'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this representation

```
^(http-|)(test-data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because there is a `?` on the `(?:http-)`. Then the regex will also match any string that contains `test-data`.

Comment: but if i remove ? then it wouldn't match just test-data